# ImportError: No module named api

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, statsmodels

I got this error message:

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sf
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-93c3fe253962>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels.formula.api as sf

ImportError: No module named api
```

I already tried to install with:

```
pip install --upgrade --no-deps statsmodels
```

But the  problem remains then I uninstalled it and I tried by conda using:

```
conda install statsmodels
```

Unfortunately, the issue remained, and then I tried by the [source](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/install.html). But I couldn't solve yet.

This is my pip list is [here](https://pastebin.com/9d9Ys9aZ%60).

This is my [conda](http://enter%20code%20here%60https://pastebin.com/MmW2hYPA).

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and my kernel is below:

```
Linux reinaldo-computer 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: I checked the github code and my local installation both work with the same import statement. By any off chance do you have a file name `statsmodels` in your project ?

Comment: I just  reboot my computer and it worked lol.
By the way, thank you so much!